# Show that the question was migrated under the "Active Questions" tab

Tags: feature-request, design, migration

I always view the "Active Questions" tab, and questions that were migrated from another site always show up like this:

[image]

Would it be possible to add something that actually tells us what happened 18 minutes ago, like this:

[image]

And then change it back to "modified" when it gets edited?

Comment: This is probably another historical artifact. A long time ago, any post that had new activity would only show the time, and no words such as "asked", "answered", and "modified" would be shown. The code for migration was probably written before they added those words.